# Mac/LaCie Backup With Time Machine

Tags: hard-drive, backup, time-machine

I have a MBP mid 2012, OS Catalina, with a Samsung 1TB SSD and want to get better about backups. I use backblaze but found it was not backing everything up when retrieving files. I bought a Lacie 2 TB HDD and did the first backup with Time Machine. Full backup is 616 GB. Other then taking two days it went fine. I ejected the HDD and did not reconnect until about a month later. Now when I reattach to backup the MBP shuts down sometime after 4hrs in, no crash report.  I thought it was overheating but moved to an open desk and still the MBP shut down. Any other thoughts?

Also, when I eject TM says “Encrypting” and stays this way, for more then an hour. Should this be expected. I’m planning on making the desk a more permanent home (bought an iPad Pro 2020 to try replacing the MBP with) but occasionally I will want to move it to connect with Ethernet instead of WIFI for faster speeds. (I live in an apt. and the tv is where the WIFI is leaving no space for the desk.) Will the eject process take more then an hour for encryption each time?

Comment: If the Mac is shutting down, then I'd say that's a problem with the power management unit. TM may be triggering it, but it's likely that other uses might do so too. Did you choose to encrypt the TM drive? I'm not sure that I'd expect it to 'encrypt' for an hour, either. Also: WifI (particularly local Wifi) isn't necessarily slower than Ethernet, particularly when there are other limiting factors, like the speed of the disk.

Comment: Does the Lacie drive have its own power source? Is the MBP connected to power when the Lacie drive is attached?

Comment: Benwiggy, other uses? Yes I encrypted the external drive. I wondered if I should remove this until I figure things out. I have been using Ethernet for my plex  library, and you are correct. I was using it last night over WIFI from the desk and it seemed to work great.

Comment: Calebx, no on the Lacie, yes MBP is always connected to power

Comment: One more question, does your Lacie drive have two USB connectors, one for power and one for data, or just one USB connector?

Comment: just one usb-c to usb-a connector